# How can I keep prepended-images after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building an education application with a series of links to external content in rails and am using jquery/javascript.

I would like, after a user has visited a link, that a 'tick' appears next to the link to show they have read it. I am doing this currently by storing information in cookies - the id of the  tag as the key and the source of the image as the value. The tick will last as long as the cookie.

Currently, after a user clicks on a link, the id of that  (the key in the cookie) gets pushed to an array. I then loop through the array and if that key matches the id then a tick appears... (that bit is ok)

My issue I am having is that when I reload the page the ticks disappear even though my cookies are till in the browser. They also disappear from the 'cookies' array

My views...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "setCookies" %>
Read some stuff <br />
<a id="a" class="link" href="http://www.google.co.uk"
target="_blank">Google says this...</a>
<br />
<a id="b" class="link" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport"
target="_blank">BBC says this...</a>
```

My Jquery...

$(document).ready(function() {
  var cookies = [];

```
$(".link").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  setCookie(id, href, 1);
  cookies.push(id)

  for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", "https://www.freepik.com/free-icon/correct-symbol_744179.htm");
    if (cookies[i] == id) {
      document.getElementById(id).prepend(elem);
    }
  }
})

function setCookie (cname, cvalue, exhours) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+exhours*60*60*1000);
  var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname+"=" + cvalue+expires + ";path=/";
}
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you try saving it in localStorage instead?

Comment: yup go with local storage since you don't want that information to float with requests, one other suggestion don't use array use hashes to keep track of visited links :)

Comment: You guys are legends. Thank you so much for your help. This was exactly what I was after! Thanks